# Renomear tabela no firebird

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Como renomear tabela no `firebird 2.5`?

Estou usando a `query`: `ALTER TABLE cliente RENAME TO clientes;`, mas aparece o erro:

> invalid toke 'rename'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor,

conforme o FAQ do Firebird não é possível renomear tabela no firebird, conforme informado neste [link](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq363/). Você pode criar uma nova tabela ou uma view selecionando dados da tabela antiga.

Answer (score 0):

Victor,

Dando uma olhada na sua pergunta, e após uma pesquisa, realmente pelo comando tradicional de `ALTER TABLE` não é possível renomear uma tabela, porém encontrei algo que possa te ajudar, da uma olha nesse comando SQL [aqui](http://andrecupini.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/renomear-uma-tabela-no-firebird.html), espero que ajude.

Comment: Update em tabela de Metadados !? Mas se funcionou mete bronca.